# how to display data if the value is acting as key in JSON

Tags: json, http, ionic-framework

I am trying to call a JSON in ionic where a specific value is acting as a key.since this key is not unique, I am unable to fetch the individual items in my html.

Here is my JSON.

```
[{"f50a6c02a3fc5a3a5d4d9391f05f3efc":
            {"key":"f50a6c02a3fc5a3a5d4d9391f05f3efc",
             "product_id":1681,
             "variation_id":0,
             "variation":[],
             "quantity":1,
             "data_hash":
             "b5c1d5ca8bae6d4896cf1807cdf763f0",
             "line_tax_data":{"subtotal":[],
                              "total":[]
                             },
             "line_subtotal":400,
             "line_subtotal_tax":0,
             "line_total":400,
             "line_tax":0,
             "data":{},
             "product_name":"Deoro Women's Gold Carat Craft Fine Diamond Ring - 6.5 US"},
     {"6d70cb65d15211726dcce4c0e971e21c":
           {"key":"6d70cb65d15211726dcce4c0e971e21c",
            "product_id":1038,
            "variation_id":0,
            "variation":[],
            "quantity":2,
            ...............
            ...............
            ...............
}]
```

how to get the json in this format where the value is acting as a key

the way I am calling the json in ionic is,

```
getCat(){
    this.http.get(url,{ withCredentials: true }).subscribe((data) => {
               this.mydata = data.json();
               this.mydata = Array.of(this.mydata);
               console.log(this.mydata)    
         },error => {
           console.log(error);
         });
}
```

Comment: You could map `Object.keys` on each of the array values to get all the keys in the object array. Then you could use the resulting array as reference when accessing your original array.

Comment: ok let me try..

Answer (score 0):

Use `map()` and iterate over such JSON using `Object.keys()` method and change the json as you want to.
Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for better understanding.